# SMS to prefilled text message on Google Pixel

Tags: android, sms, google-pixel

I am trying to create a link in an email that will open a mobile device's default texting app if pushed. Here is what I have so far:

```
a href="sms:;?&body=This%20is%20the%20body%20message."
```

I have tested it and it seems to work on iOS devices as well as some Android devices. However, on a Google Pixel 3, it opens the default messaging app but shows an error which reads `Could not start conversation.`

How can I change my code to successfully open a conversation with a blank recipient?

Comment: Even with a number, I can't seem to get any pre-filled text on my Google Pixel 3, so I'm curious if anyone finds a solution.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trial and error, I was able to prefill the Pixel (3XL), iOS (simulated in Xcode), and macOS Messages using the following structure:

**Pixel:** `sms://+1${PHONE}/?body=${encodedString}`
**iOS:** `sms://+1${PHONE}/&body=${encodedString}`

Comment: This is amazing! I've been looking for an actually working example of the for so long

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try from a link, I think you need a number and replace ; with ?

`<a href="sms:444-222-3333?body=Hello World!">Send SMS</a>`

For non iOS you want to use (For your Pixel Example)
`sms:phone_number?body=The_Message`

For iOS you want to use
`sms:phone_number;body=The_Message`

Comment: Hey Matt, For some reason that made the link non-clickable. I double-checked that I implemented your code accurately and it still wasn't working.